# systemd-networkd dhcp_hostname option

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, dhcp

I have configured `systemd-networkd` to setup my networking, I have created vlan10 and i want to client send hostname to DHCP to register in my DDNS server so question is does `networkd` support `DHCP_HOSTNAME=` option?

```
[root@localhost network]# cat vlan10.network
[Match]
Name=vlan10

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

I have multiple VLAN and i want to send two different vlan hostname to dhcp server to register them in `DNS` for example

vlan10 will send hostname `foo.vlan10.example.com`

vlan 20 will send hostname `foo.vlan20.examplee.com`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since systemd 223 you can do this. It introduces two options for systemd-networkd

**SendHostname=** When true (the default), the machine's hostname will be sent to the DHCP server.

**Hostname=** Use this value for the hostname which is sent to the DHCP server, instead of machine's hostname.

Options must be set in [DHCP] section in your .network file. So from your example vlan10.network should look like

```
[Match]
Name=vlan10

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[DHCP]
SendHostname=True
Hostname=foo.vlan10.example.com
```

Comment: I am using `219` version on CentOS7  :( that is the problem i think... I have tired to upgrade systemd on centOS7 but it throwing bunch of dependencies